# Conditions for finite bandwidth

Tags: signal-analysis, bandwidth

I'd like to know which conditions must be satisfied in order to get a signal with a finite bandwidth.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In order to get a signal with a finite bandwidth, the bandwidth of the signal must be limited so that it is not infinite. Is that what you want to know ?

Comment: in the time domain

Comment: Finite support in one domain (frequency) requires infinite support in the other (time).

Comment: @hotpaw2 does infinite support in time domain guarantees finite support in frequency domain ?

Comment: No.  Necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: @hotpaw2 can you show an example of a signal that has an infinite support in the time domain, but not a finite support in the frequency domain please?

Comment: Any Gaussian distribution/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us  stick to traditional functions, considering the almost everywhere equivalence class.  From an actual signal perspective, I am leaving distributions aside.

According to the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz.27s_Paley.E2.80.93Wiener_theorem), functions with compact frequency support (corresponding to Bernstein spaces) can be extended
from the real line to the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ as **entire functions
of exponential type**; entire functions are holomorphic at all finite points of $\mathbb{C}$ ,  exponential type means that $|f(z)|\le C e^{a|z|}$. They can be called $B$-functions.

So they inherit from all their properties: no bounded support in time, infinite differentiability, Taylor expansion everywhere, controlled decay at infinity...